# Symfony 2.1.6, Sass and Compass. How do I enable FireSass support?

Tags: sass, symfony-2.1

I have Symfony 2.1.6, sass and compass working well together.

How do I get it to generate FireSass info?

It seems that I need to give sass the --debug-info switch but I haven't had much luck understanding the assetic bundle config in Symfony.

My app/config/config.xml contains the following

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass: ~
        compass: ~
```

That worked without any other configuration. I already had sass and compass installed because I've been using the Zen theme in Drupal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by putting this in parameters.yml

```
assetic.filter.compass.debug: true
```

I'm not sure if it's the best way.

Also, I don't know how to do it if I was just using Sass without Compass. assetic.filter.sass.debug: true does not work.

I'm still interested in any other info to clarify.